# Navigation drawer hang when getting data from server

Tags: android, json

In android application, i am using navigation drawer which has 6 fragments on side drawer and each fragment need to get some  data from server which make it hang or delay in opening/closing  the drawer and making my application performance very slow.Please suggest me the best way to get data from server and set to textbox in fragment .

code to get data from server class

```
public String getName() {
        JSONObject ob = getBalnce();
        String name = null;
        try {
            name = ob.getString("UserName");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return name;
    }

    public String getBalance() {
        JSONObject ob = getBalnce();
        String bal = null;
        try {
            bal = ob.getString("UserBalance");
            if (bal == null) {
                bal = "₹ " + "0";
            } else {

                bal = "₹  " + bal;
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bal;
    }

    public static JSONObject getBalnce() {
        final JSONObject toSend = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject ob = null;
        {
            try {


                toSend.put("Id", classname.Id);

                String jsonStr = toSend.toString();
                DataPost transmitter = new DataPost();

                data = transmitter.execute(jsonStr,
                        url).get();
                data = data.replaceAll("\n", "");

                JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(data);
                ob = obj.getJSONObject(0);
                java.lang.System.gc();



            } catch (JSONException e) {


                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return ob;

    }
```

code to get  and set data in fragment

```
Balance cm = new Balance();

        name = cm.getName();




        if (uname.length() > 10) {
            name.setText("Hi," + " " + name.substring(0, 10));
    }
```

same problem in all fragment, when we switch from one drawer to other .

Comment: are u using `AsynTask` for communication with the server?

Comment: using async task to get data in class DataPost transmitter = new DataPost();

                data = transmitter.execute(jsonStr,
                        url).get();